# Model-based clustering evaluation with BIC

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, model-selection, bic

Let's say I have fitted two models using EM-clustering and they differ in both the number of clusters and are fitted on different subset of features (chosen from the same set of features).

Could I use BIC to compare these two models or would the BIC values be incomparable when the feature space differ?

If no, how would I compare these models in quantifiable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the BIC is useful for comparing cluster solutions. For instance, see the many CV threads on this topic on the right hand side of this thread. If there's a problem with using it, it's in your implicit assumption that a single metric is sufficient for evaluation and comparison of these solutions. To me, an ensemble approach to evaluation is preferable, particularly against fixed out-of-sample data to confirm that the clusters even exist.

There is no shortage of evaluatory metrics for clustering. Marina Meila has an excellent paper on cluster comparison where she reviews several measures of association as well as proposing her own information theoretic criterion that is straightforward to implement. It's worth a look.

http://www.stat.washington.edu/mmp/Papers/compare-colt.pdf

You haven't indicated how you are using these results but if it involves scoring completely new data, then another useful step is evaluating how "recoverable" the solutions are on a reduced set of predictors such as would likely be available from an external data source or vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the ensamble tip, but I still don't understand if the evaluatory metrics can be used to compare models fitted on a data set with different dimensons (different number of predictors)?

Comment: Of course they can. BIC does this automatically in fitting the function by adjusting for the number of parameters. For others, it's on a metric by metric basis.